# Merge non-empty lines of the two unicode text files, using windows batch

Tags: text, batch-file, replace

**We have** 2 Unicode files. One of them contains lines that are missing in another file. Like so:

```
1. 
2. bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
3. 
4. ddddddddddddddddddddd
5. eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

```
1. aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
2. 
3. ccccccccccccccccc
4.
5.
```

**We want** to merge them into third file that will contain all lines:

```
1. aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
2. bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
3. ccccccccccccccccc
4. ddddddddddddddddddddd
5. eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

**Notes:**
a,b,c,d,e - can be any text.
line numbers are just for illustration purposes, they are not present in actual files.

I created this question with "batch-file" tag, but I am open to any suggestions about how to achieve this. Of course better not to involve something like C++

Comment: What is the criteria of merge? Is it lexicographical order, or actual files will contain blank lines in appropriate places, as in your sample? Can identical lines be present in both files?

Comment: yes, both files contains exactly the same number of lines and if it is blank in one file, it will surely be filled in another one. Of course maybe some lines are empty in both files so we'll end up adding nothing to nothing, but there is never 2 full lines in both files.

Comment: simply saying, this kind of algorithm will work:
1) take one of the files as a base
2) in second file for each line check if its blank
3) if blank - move to next line, if not - add it to base file then move to next line.
However i'd prefer to save output in new file instead of altering one of the sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that no line starts with a colon,
first we read each line from two files into two arrays, including blank lines - there is a special hack for this, since normal for skips blank lines.
And then just concatenate elements with from both arrays with identical index, and output into results.txt :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('type "file1.txt" ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
    set /A i+=1
    set arr1[!i!]=%%B
)

set i=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('type "file2.txt" ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
    set /A i+=1
    set arr2[!i!]=%%B
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do echo.!arr1[%%i]!!arr2[%%i]!>> result.txt
```

Comment: It almost works, but in some places, I assume where both files have blank line, it writes text "ECHO is off."
I am marking this as an answer, cause I can remove "ECHO is off." as 2nd step, but if you know how to fix this, please reply. 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have edited my answer - just include dot after last echo command.